# Can one use NRI and IDI in regularized cox-regression?

Tags: r, classification, regularization, cox-model, glmnet

I have a dataset with 1500 patients for which I want to predict the outcome of death.
I wanted to utilize multivariate cox-regression in a model containing biomarkers and other covariates. I was told to use the C-statistic, NRI and IDI to evaluate the model performance on classification.
I am not quite sure how to approach these classification methods in the framework of glmnnet and regularized Cox-regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been serious criticisms of IDI and NRI.  And the $c$-index is not sensitive enough for comparing two models.  I like to use measures that apply to any model and are very efficient.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue) for several efficient and simple measures to choose from.